# Can you explain this Spring environment variable resolution?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, environment-variables, logback

The [Spring Boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) have the following sample logging file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Can you help me understand the line `${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}`? What are the `-` for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like Bash, Logback uses `:-` as its default value operator. The line in question is setting the `LOG_FILE` property:

- If `LOG_FILE` is already set, use that
- Otherwise, if `LOG_PATH` is set, use that suffixed with `spring.log`
- Otherwise, if `LOG_TEMP` is set, use that suffixed with `/spring.log`
- Otherwise, if `java.io.tmpdir` is set, use that suffixed with `/spring.log`
- Otherwise use `/tmp/spring.log`

Comment: the logic you quoted is a bit different from what the code actually means. e.g. for point 2, it should be suffixed with `spring.log` instead of `/spring.log`.  Similar for the 4th point

Comment: Good catch. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation using if-else. I don't think @adrian's point is correct though. `LOG_PATH`, `LOG_TEMP` and `java.io.tempdir` are all directories, and in order to put a file in any of those directories, the suffix must be `/spring.log`, not `spring.log`.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I have no idea on what was stored in those variable. What I said was simply based on the expression quoted in question. It may look irrational but it is not my concern.

Comment: When you set LOG_FILE to "myapp.log" through logging.file property in application.properties, Spring is still using /tmp/spring.log in addition to myapp.log

Answer (score 5):

It has nothing to do with Spring.

Logback XML configuration itself has such kind of placeholder handling to replace the placeholders with variable.  The syntax for placeholder in logback is `${VARNAME}`, and if you want default value if `VARNAME` is not present, you can do it by `${VARNAME:-DEFAULT}` (ref: [Logback Configuration)](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#nestedSubst).  Yes, a `:-`, follow by the default value.

Then what you quote is easy to understand:

```
${LOG_FILE:-                                                             }
            ${LOG_PATH:-                                      }spring.log
                        ${LOG_TEMP:-                        }/
                                     ${java.io.tmpdir:-    }
                                                       /tmp
```

(Do you actually need explanation on what the above means?)